# why we need "-'0'" to modify array?

Tags: c

This is code from C by Dennis Ritchie, chapter "Array":

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Why do we need `-'0'` in this line?

```
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

If I change it to `++ndigit[c]`, the program doesn't work properly. Why can't we just write `++ndigit[c]`?

I already read the explanation of the book, but I don't understand it.

> This works only if '0', '1', ..., '9' have consecutive increasing values. Fortunately, this is true for all character sets. By definition, chars are just small integers, so char variables and constants are identical to ints in arithmetic expressions. This is natural and convenient; for example c-'0' is an integer expression with a value between 0 and 9 corresponding to the character '0' to '9' stored in c, and thus a valid subscript for the array ndigit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to understand why we need "-'0'" you first need to understand ASCII table - http://www.asciitable.com/

now you need to understand that every character in C is represented by a number between 0 and 127 ( 255 for extended ).

for example if you'll print the character '0' for his numeric value:

`printf( "%d", '0' );`

> output: 48

now you've declared an array of size 10 - `ndigit[ 10 ]`, where the `n` cell represent the number of times the number `n` was given as input.

so if you receive '0' as input you'd want to do `ndigit[ 0 ]++` so you need to convert from char to integer. and you can do that by subtracting 48 ( = '0' )

thats why we use the line `++ndigit[c-'0'];`

if c = '5', we will get

`++ndigit['5' - '0']`

`++ndigit[ 53 - 48 ]`

`++ndigit[ 5 ]`

exactly like we wanted it to be

Comment: The idea of "Fortunately, this is true for all character sets" is that this does **not** depend on specific character encodings such as ASCII. It is "true for all character sets" because it is in the C specifications. `[c-'0']` would also work for a character set where the encoding of `"0"` is `0`, and then `ndigit['0']++` would work the same. (Apart from that your answer is correct – just wanted to point out the main point that *it does not depend on ASCII* ;)

Comment: thanks for that! I was using ASCII for it to be more clear, but you are absolutely correct

Comment: you explained it better than MikeCat!!

Answer (score 3):

`c = getchar()` will store the character code read to `c`, and it is differ from the integer that the character stands for.

Quote from [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.2.1 Character sets

> . In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
>   value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
>   the value of the previous.

As this shows, the character codes for decimal digits are continuous, so you can convert the character code of decimal digits to the integer that the characters stand for by subtracting `'0'`, which is `0`'s character code, from the character code.

In conclusion, `c-'0'` yields the integer that the character in `c` stands for.

Comment: And `++ndigit[c]` (more precisely, just the bit `ndigit[c]`) does not work because the *value* of the character `"0"` can be way beyond the allowed indexes for  `ndigit[10];` (in current implementations of C which use ASCII, its value would be `48`).